# RegCreateKeyEx returning Error 87 aka "INVALID_PARAMETER"

Tags: c++, windows, registry, winreg

I need to implement a wrapper class around Winreg.h library.

Problem: All functions work correctly except RegCreateKeyEx, when I try to pass the parameters it returns Error 87.

Example:

When I hardcode the subkey inside the function it works just fine.

```
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    DWORD dc;
    int rc = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_USERS, L"AppUser\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, &dc);
```

But when I parameterized the function like this so I can make the subkey variable and make resursive calls to it it produces Error 87.

```
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    DWORD dc;
    const std::wstring szSub = L"AppUser\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer";
    LPCWSTR lpszSub = szSub.c_str();
    int rc = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_USERS, lpszSub, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, &dc);
```

I'm just starting with this library so I don't know what I'm missing, maybe a formatting error or something else. I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: Hmm. I get a return value of 87 from your *first* code snippet. But both succeed if I use the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key as the first argument. Did you maybe make a typo?

Comment: Should the path be "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer"

Comment: Yeah it was a typo, the SOFTWARE part should not be there, but what I need to do is create a key under HKEY_USERS/AppUser, AppUser is a different user in the system, what is do is first load the user hive with RegLoad, it loads correctly and then try to add the subkeys for that user. when i do that like in the first snippet it works, the second one it does not.

Comment: @Illmare "*what I need to do is create a key under HKEY_USERS/AppUser*" - DO NOT try to open `HKEY_USERS\AppUser` directly. The *correct* way to access a different user's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive is to use either [`RegOpenCurrentUser()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopencurrentuser) or [`LoadUserProfile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-loaduserprofilew) instead.